# Как я могу отслеживать изменения в sqlite3 в golang?

Tags: golang, sqlite3

всем привет!
Я пользуюсь библиотекой "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3" для работы с базой данных.
Мне нужно отслеживать изменения, внесенные в базу данных, и после того, как эти изменения будут завершены, выполнить некоторый код.
Например, существует таблица Products с полями name и id
Я хочу получить уведомление после изменения поля имени

Как я могу это сделать?
любое решение
Спасибо

Comment: Если вы можете изменять схему БД, то можно добавить [триггер](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) на изменение поля, который будет обновлять счётчик в некой отдельной таблице (которую надо создать). А далее, вам надо периодически (раз в секунду/минуту) считывать этот счётчик и сравнивать его значение с предыдущим. Если изменился, значит произошло обновление.

Answer (score 1):

Для типа SQLiteConn есть функция [RegisterUpdateHook](https://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#SQLiteConn.RegisterUpdateHook)

Эта функция регистрирует обработчик, который вызывается после INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.